# Delphi 7: an abstract class through VFI

Tags: delphi, inheritance, delphi-7

Is it possible in Delphi 7 to create an abstract class that can be inherited through the Visual Form Inheritance technique? If so, please, provide an example.

The task is this. I want to create a form that will serve as a base form for two other forms that will inherit all the properties of that form. The two inheriting forms will be used for adding new stuff to the database (creating a product item, for example) and editing that stuff. So, I guess the base form should be thought of as an abstract class that should have okay and cancel buttons and things like that which all inheriting classes will share. Well, it is obviously an abstract class, because there is no other use of the form other than being a form to base other forms on.

Here's a simple diagram to make the point clearer:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to achieve with that abstract class (especially why it has to be abstract)?

Comment: Can't you just try it out yourself? Set up a couple of forms with VFI, give the base class an abstract method, and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

First of all we need to define what abstract class means. There appear to me to be two competing definitions:

1. An abstract class is one that cannot be instantiated. This is the most commonly used definition.
2. An abstract class is one that contains more than one abstract method.

Since Delphi no language mechanism for enforcing definition 1, it would appear that definition 2 is the definition that applies to this question.

And the answer to the question is that classes that contain abstract methods can be used with Visual Form Inheritance.

Modern versions of Delphi do allow you to decorate classes with the `abstract` keyword. However, this has no effect. You can still instantiate such a class. It is my understanding that the `abstract` keyword was added for the benefit of the Delphi .net compiler.

Again, in modern versions of Delphi, you can configure the compiler to treat instantiation of classes with abstract methods as a compilation error. That's probably the closest you can get in Delphi to definition 1.

However, even that does not fully adhere to definition 1 since those classes can be instantiated through RTTI or virtual constructors. And the mechanism by which a designed component is instantiated is a perfect example.

Take this class for example:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  public
    procedure Boo; virtual; abstract;
  end;
```

Even if you set the option for *W2000 Constructing instance containing abstract method* to *Error*, you can still let the framework instantiate the class. It's only if you write `TForm1.Create` that the compiler objects.

Comment: @All Thanks for telling me that I was talking nonsense in my deleted answer.

Comment: Alright. I think I should just create an ordinary form class and forget about this abstraction thing.

Comment: What do you want to make abstract? All you've got with Delphi is methods that can be abstract.

Answer (score 2):

You use the term *abstract*, but reading your question, I seriously doubt you really mean it the way *abstract* within Delphi is defined. I think you mean the term *abstract* in the general plain spoken way: you want to design a form with parts that have to be altered or added by descendants. *Abstract* methods in Delphi mean class routines without implementation. It does not matter though, because it is perfectly possible to design a base form, with or without abstract methods.

You can create a setup as shown in your picture/diagram as follows:

- Design a form `TBaseForm` with 2 Edits, 2 Labels, 2 Buttons and 1 ActionList,
- Add 3 actions to the ActionList: Create, Save and Cancel,
- Assign the Cancel action to CancelButton.Action in advance,
- Save the form,
- Design a new form, inherited from TBaseForm, with the menu command: File > New > Other > [Project Name] > BaseForm
- You will have a new form that has the edits, labels, buttons and actions,
- Assign the Save action to the other button's action property,
- Give it a "Edit Item" caption,
- Save the form, and repeat it for the "Create New Item"-form.

The base form may have abstract methods, if you want to. When you create a TBaseForm instance at runtime, the compiler will give a warning *constructing instance of 'TBaseForm' containing abstract method 'TBaseForm.MethodName'*. It remains a warning, until you invoke the method at runtime which will produce an *abstract error*. Creating a descendant form which implements that method, then there will be no warning. Creating forms with abstract methods in the designer does not produce warnings. Runtime errors then may still occur though.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot create an "abstract" base form in Delphi Visual Form Inheritance in the strict Delphi sense of the word "abstract".

However, from your description it doesn't sound like you actually need a strictly abstract base form. You don't mention a requirement for defining abstract methods at all.

It sounds like you just need a base form from which you create multiple differently specialized descendants that can share UI and implementation with the base form.

That's what VFI is for, so yes, you can do that.

Comment: So, what's your take on the definition of "abstract class"?

Comment: I this OP just means a base class that isn't instantiated (because it doesn't do anything useful on its own).

Comment: Actually I'm interested in hearing what you take *abstract class* to mean. After being severely corrected earlier today, I think it's a class that cannot be instantiated. Is that what you take *abstract class* to mean?

Comment: Yes, the strict definition of abstract class is one which contains abstract methods which prevents the class from being instantiated. Or in C#, it's just a class marked with abstract.

Answer (score 0):

I have Succeed to create a Demo with a BaseForm has Abstract Methodes and is work as charm ...
my IDE is Rad Studio RIO 
my BaseForm code:

```
unit UBaseForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TBaseForm = class(TForm)
    Lbl_IndexPage: TLabel;
    procedure Abstracted_Event(Sender: TObject); virtual; abstract;
    procedure Abstracted_Proc; virtual; abstract;
    function Abstracted_Func: string; virtual; abstract;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  procedure Get_SubForm(var Ref; AFormClass: TFormClass;
  aOwner: TComponent; aParent: TWinControl);

var
  BaseForm: TBaseForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Get_SubForm(var Ref; AFormClass: TFormClass;
  aOwner: TComponent; aParent: TWinControl);
var
  Instance: TBaseForm;
begin
  if not Assigned(TBaseForm(Ref)) then
  begin
    Instance       := TBaseForm(AFormClass.NewInstance);
    TBaseForm(Ref) := Instance;
    Instance.Create(aOwner);
  end
  else Instance := TBaseForm(Ref);

  Instance.Parent      := aParent;
  Instance.Align       := alClient;
  Instance.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  Instance.OnShow      := Instance.Abstracted_Event;
  Instance.Show;
end;

end.
```

in my APP i have three Forms can inherit all the properties of that BaseForm Above Even the Methodes ...

```
unit UFirstPage;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  UBaseForm,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TFrmFirstPage = class(TBaseForm)
    Pnl_1: TPanel;
    Edt_Abst_Msg_Event: TEdit;
    Pnl_2: TPanel;
    Pnl_3: TPanel;
    Btn_Get_Abstract_Func: TButton;
    Btn_Get_Abstract_Proc: TButton;
    procedure Btn_Get_Abstract_FuncClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Btn_Get_Abstract_ProcClick(Sender: TObject);
  published
    procedure Abstracted_Event(Sender: TObject); override;
    procedure Abstracted_Proc; override;
    function Abstracted_Func: string; override;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FrmFirstPage: TFrmFirstPage;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TFrmFirstPage }

{$REGION ' Overridden Abstract Methodes ..'}
procedure TFrmFirstPage.Abstracted_Event(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  Pnl_1.Color := clBlue; Pnl_2.Color := clGray; Pnl_3.Color := clRed;
  Edt_Abst_Msg_Event.Text  := 'All this Properties can changed using [Abstracted_Event] | (Owner Form is: ['+ Self.ClassName +'])';
end;

function TFrmFirstPage.Abstracted_Func: string;
begin
  Result := 'I''m Just an Override of Abstracted_Func ['+ Self.ClassName +']';
end;

procedure TFrmFirstPage.Abstracted_Proc;
begin
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('I''m Just an Override of Abstracted_Proc ['+ Self.ClassName +']');
end;
{$ENDREGION}

procedure TFrmFirstPage.Btn_Get_Abstract_FuncClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(Abstracted_Func);
end;

procedure TFrmFirstPage.Btn_Get_Abstract_ProcClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Abstracted_Proc;
end;

end.
```

[image]

my Second Form:

```
unit USecondPage;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  UBaseForm,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TFrmSecondPage = class(TBaseForm)
    Lbl_Abst_Msg_Event: TLabel;
    Lbl_1: TLabel;
    Lbl_2: TLabel;
    Lbl_3: TLabel;
    Btn_Do_Abst_Proc: TButton;
    Btn_Get_Abst_Func: TButton;
    procedure Btn_Do_Abst_ProcClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Btn_Get_Abst_FuncClick(Sender: TObject);
  published
    procedure Abstracted_Event(Sender: TObject); override;
    procedure Abstracted_Proc; override;
    function Abstracted_Func: string; override;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FrmSecondPage: TFrmSecondPage;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TFrmSecondPage }

{$REGION ' Overridden Abstract Methodes ..'}
procedure TFrmSecondPage.Abstracted_Event(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  Lbl_1.Font.Color := clBlue; Lbl_2.Font.Color := clGray; Lbl_3.Font.Color := clRed;
  Lbl_Abst_Msg_Event.Caption := 'All this Properties can changed using [Abstracted_Event] | (Owner Form is: ['+ Self.ClassName +'])';
end;

function TFrmSecondPage.Abstracted_Func: string;
begin
  Result := 'I''m Just an Override of Abstracted_Func ['+ Self.ClassName +']';
end;

procedure TFrmSecondPage.Abstracted_Proc;
begin
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('I''m Just an Override of Abstracted_Proc ['+ Self.ClassName +']');
end;
{$ENDREGION}

procedure TFrmSecondPage.Btn_Do_Abst_ProcClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Abstracted_Proc;
end;

procedure TFrmSecondPage.Btn_Get_Abst_FuncClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(Abstracted_Func);
end;

end.
```

[image]

my third Form:

```
unit UThirdPage;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  UBaseForm,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TFrmThirdPage = class(TBaseForm)
  published
    procedure Abstracted_Event(Sender: TObject); override;
    procedure Abstracted_Proc; override;
    function Abstracted_Func: string; override;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FrmThirdPage: TFrmThirdPage;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TFrmThirdPage }

{$REGION ' Overridden Abstract Methodes ..'}
procedure TFrmThirdPage.Abstracted_Event(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
// your Code Goes Here ..
// call this methode or fill it with code Not a Mandatory :)
// The Mandatory thing is to implement this Methodes Exactly where BASEFORM HAS & without Missing any one of them from the Base Class...
// Enjoy ...
end;

function TFrmThirdPage.Abstracted_Func: string;
begin
// your Code Goes Here ..
// call this methode or fill it with code Not a Mandatory :)
// Enjoy ...
end;

procedure TFrmThirdPage.Abstracted_Proc;
begin
  inherited;
// your Code Goes Here ..
// call this methode or fill it with code Not a Mandatory :)
// Enjoy ...
end;
{$ENDREGION}

end.
```

[image]

my Main Form:

```
unit UMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls,
// My Abstracted Views ..
  UFirstPage,
  USecondPage,
  UThirdPage;

type
  TFrmMain = class(TForm)
    Pnl_ToolBar: TPanel;
    Pnl_StatusBar: TPanel;
    Btn_Previous: TButton;
    Btn_Next: TButton;
    Notebook_SubForms: TNotebook;
    Pnl_First_PAGE: TPanel;
    Pnl_Second_PAGE: TPanel;
    Pnl_Third_PAGE: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Notebook_SubFormsPageChanged(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Btn_NextClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Btn_PreviousClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FrmMain: TFrmMain;

implementation

uses
// My Abstracted Base Template ..
  UBaseForm;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFrmMain.Btn_NextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case Notebook_SubForms.PageIndex of
    0:begin
        Notebook_SubForms.PageIndex := 1;
      end;
    1:begin
        Notebook_SubForms.PageIndex := 2;
      end;
    2:begin
        Notebook_SubForms.PageIndex := 0;
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFrmMain.Btn_PreviousClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case Notebook_SubForms.PageIndex of
    0:begin
        Notebook_SubForms.PageIndex := 2;
      end;
    1:begin
        Notebook_SubForms.PageIndex := 0;
      end;
    2:begin
        Notebook_SubForms.PageIndex := 1;
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Get_SubForm(FrmFirstPage, TFrmFirstPage, Self, Pnl_First_PAGE);
end;

procedure TFrmMain.Notebook_SubFormsPageChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case Notebook_SubForms.PageIndex of
    0:begin
        Get_SubForm(FrmFirstPage, TFrmFirstPage, Self, Pnl_First_PAGE);
        if Assigned(FrmSecondPage) then FreeAndNil(FrmSecondPage);
        if Assigned(FrmThirdPage) then FreeAndNil(FrmThirdPage);
      end;
    1:begin
        Get_SubForm(FrmSecondPage, TFrmSecondPage, Self, Pnl_Second_PAGE);
        if Assigned(FrmFirstPage) then FreeAndNil(FrmFirstPage);
        if Assigned(FrmThirdPage) then FreeAndNil(FrmThirdPage);
      end;
    2:begin
        Get_SubForm(FrmThirdPage, TFrmThirdPage, Self, Pnl_Third_PAGE);
        if Assigned(FrmSecondPage) then FreeAndNil(FrmSecondPage);
        if Assigned(FrmSecondPage) then FreeAndNil(FrmSecondPage);
      end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

[image]

When Compile 0 error and 0 Warning..
Result:
[image]

[image]

[image]

link to download the whole demo from my Github Repo [here](https://github.com/RobertoGitRepo/BaseForm-With-Abstract-Methodes).
the Demo can work Also in Delphi 7 (i test it) :)